# APC not enabled for google-app-engine on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, google-app-engine

It says here, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions, that many modules are enabled in the PHP runtime for App Engine. But many of these modules are not enabled, nor provided, when you download the GoogleAppEngineLauncher for Mac OS X and start developing on your local machine.

Specifically, APC. It works fine once I deploy my app to GAE, but doesn't work on local development.

How does one enable these? How does one download/compile them for specific inclusion within the GoogleAppEngineLauncher?

For maximum compatibility, I'd rather not compile my own PHP for GAEL to use (I found documentation on how to do that as last resort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Running_a_custom_php_install), the only modules that are missing are "mcrypt and gd", so you probably don't need to tweak a lot to be able to use the SDK, unless you are using one of those two modules.

In that case, then I think your only viable solution is to use your own php-cgi interpreter and specify its path with --php_executable when starting your devserver.

Alternatively, as you're on MacOSX, you might be able to use MacPorts to do this (I don't know MacPorts mind you, so it may be harder than you anticipate)